# How to perform Java Bytecode liveness analysis?

Tags: java, bytecode

I am specifically trying to determine how many initialized variables in a program are "live" at the end of it. I have multiple class files that I have disassembled into one file using

```
java -c file1 file2 ... >> out.txt
```

How would I go about this. Could I simply count the first occurrence of a variable, and then check if it is ever referred to again in the program? This has the big assumption of sequential bytecode however, which is not necessarily true.

Is liveness analysis possible for functions as well?

Comment: You need to add instrumentation to to the code and run the program

Comment: Is there an automated way to do this? I am analyzing a large number of JAR files and rather not modify the code directly.

Comment: bytecode instrumentation does not require you to modify the code directly - I will provide an answer shortly

Comment: What do you mean by live variable?

Comment: Do you mean, declared and/or initialized? Used variable?

Comment: @Pier-AlexandreBouchard : I am defining a variable as live if it holds a value that may be needed in the future; i.e. it is used after initialization by some function, etc, at some point. The variable is "dead" if it is initialized but never used again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Runtime [liveness analysis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Live_variable_analysis) for variables which are actually properties guarded by get/set accessors can be translated to problem of measuring the [code coverage](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_coverage) of the set accessors.

There are already Java tools that can measure it automatically (no inventing of some instrumentation magic suggested by @amir-afghani would be needed)

See also:

- [Stack Overflow: What is your favourite code coverage tool(s)? (Free and non-free)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39329/what-is-your-favourite-code-coverage-tools-free-and-non-free)
- [Wikipedia: Java Code Coverage Tools](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Code_Coverage_Tools)

Answer (score 0):

Read [this](http://www.javalobby.org/java/forums/t19309.html) article.  Long story short:

You want to intercept each class thats loaded in your program while its executing, and replace it with a version that has been instrumented in the desired location (for example, at method entry).  This isn't hard to do with `java.lang.instrument` and a bytecode engineering library like ASM.